# how to execute multiple async queries in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to execute multiple queries asynchronously. Now for that I have searched but nothing special I found.

Ya one thing I found is of Asynctools at http://code.google.com/p/asynctools/

but in the code given i am getting the error

NameError: global name 'AsyncMultiTask' is not defined

and I dont kn what to import for that. so please anyone can help me for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of months ago Guido announced a new experimental datastore API, which allows asynchronous calls:

http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-app-engine-datastore-api.html